# fuzzywuzzy match in python with if condition

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzywuzzy

i have two set of data were i need to find the similar matches using fuzzywuzzy or any other options,

Data set contains the column as below mentioned(Columns are same in the both the Data set but rows differ)

SLNo|Product Name|Brand

first i need to find the brand similarity if the brand similarity is greater than 95 then i need to check the product name similarity

i have tried below Code

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import process, fuzz

Bl=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Datas\BLRL3.xlsx')
master=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Datas\MO.xlsx')

actual_Name= []
similarity = []
brandsimilarity = []

for i in Bl.Productname:
        for j in Bl.Brand:
                brandratio = process.extract( i, master.Brand, limit=1,scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio)
                brandsimilarity.append(brandratio[0][1])
                if brandsimilarity > 95:
                        ratio = process.extract( i, master.Productname, limit=1,scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio)
                        actual_Productname.append(ratio[0][0])
                        similarity.append(ratio[0][1])


Bl['actual_Name'] = pd.Series(actual_Name)
Bl['similarity'] = pd.Series(similarity)
Bl['brandsimilarity']=pd.Series(brandsimilarity)

Bl.to_csv("oput2503-2.csv",index = False)
```

Error: if brandsimilarity > 95:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Answer (score 0):

As the error state it is a TypeError to compare a list with a integer.
To achieve what you want you should not use

```
brandsimilarity.append(brandratio[0][1])
```

but

```
brandsimilarity = brandratio[0][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

'''MasterSKU = [] SKU_Similarity = [] Mastergeneric = [] Generic_or_Salt_Similarity = [] for i in df_2.Generic_Or_Salt: for j in df_2.SKU: Masterratio = process.extract( j, df.SKU, limit=1) MasterSKU= Masterratio[0][0] SKU_Similarity= Masterratio[0][1] if SKU_Similarity>95: ratio = process.extract( i, df['Generic/Salt'], limit=1) Mastergeneric.append(ratio[0][0]) Generic_or_Salt_Similarity.append(ratio[0][1])

df_2['MasterSKU'] = pd.Series(MasterSKU) df_2['MasterSKU'] = df_2['MasterSKU'] df_2['SKU_Similarity'] = pd.Series(SKU_Similarity) df_2['Mastergeneric'] = pd.Series(Mastergeneric) df_2['Mastergeneric'] = df_2['Mastergeneric'] df_2['Generic_or_Salt_Similarity'] = pd.Series(Generic_or_Salt_Similarity)'''

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Can you please edit your code to improve formatting (see this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help) and also add an explanation on how your code solves the problem?